# BigQuery duplicated rank() numbers

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, rank

I have a transaction table with account_no, order_id, start_date, end_date and ranking. I am trying to rank the transactions based on their start date and end date. But the problem is all the transaction have similar start and end dates, i can't possible rank the transactions based on their date.

My code

```
select distinct account_id,order_id,order_validfrom_date as start_date,order_validto_date as end_date, 
 rank() OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY order_validfrom_date desc ,order_validto_date desc  ) AS ranking, 

from  `datamart_dimsum.rpt_dly_dimsum_subscription_details` 

where order_validfrom_date <= '2020-01-14'  and  account_id in (216223
)  order by account_id, order_id,order_validfrom_date,order_validto_date
```

Output

```
account_id | order_id |  start_date  | end_date   | ranking
  216223     482847      2017-10-09    2017-11-08      1
  216223     472121      2017-10-09    2017-11-08      1
  216223     312312      2017-10-09    2017-11-08      1
```

Is there any way to rank the first transaction as 1 despite same start date and end dates? I had tried the ROW_NUMBER() function but failed.

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: the first account_id with ranking 1, and the rest 2 and 3

Answer (score 3):

Use `row_number()`.  `rank()` is supposed to return duplicates:

```
 row_number() over (partition by account_id
                    order by order_validfrom_date desc, order_validto_date desc
                   ) as ranking,
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the order_id in the `ORDER BY` clause?

```
select distinct account_id,order_id,order_validfrom_date as start_date,order_validto_date as end_date, 
 rank() OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY order_validfrom_date desc ,order_validto_date, order_id desc  ) AS ranking, 

from  `datamart_dimsum.rpt_dly_dimsum_subscription_details` 

where order_validfrom_date <= '2020-01-14'  and  account_id in (216223
)  order by account_id, order_id,order_validfrom_date,order_validto_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

I see two equally reasonable options for you

> Option 1 - just add another field as a tie breaker

In your case `order_id` looks like should work as it most likely unique in your table - so below should work

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT 
  account_id,
  order_id,
  order_validfrom_date AS start_date,
  order_validto_date AS end_date, 
  RANK() OVER(
    PARTITION BY account_id 
    ORDER BY order_validfrom_date DESC, order_validto_date DESC, order_id DESC -- added order_id here < this is the only change 
  ) AS ranking, 
FROM `datamart_dimsum.rpt_dly_dimsum_subscription_details` 
WHERE order_validfrom_date <= '2020-01-14'  
AND account_id IN (216223)
ORDER BY account_id, order_id DESC, order_validfrom_date, order_validto_date
```

> Option 2 - just replace RANK with ROW_NUMBER, as in below example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT 
  account_id,
  order_id,
  order_validfrom_date AS start_date,
  order_validto_date AS end_date, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER( -- ROW_NUMBER instead of RANK  is the only change here
    PARTITION BY account_id 
    ORDER BY order_validfrom_date DESC, order_validto_date DESC
  ) AS ranking, 
FROM `datamart_dimsum.rpt_dly_dimsum_subscription_details` 
WHERE order_validfrom_date <= '2020-01-14'  
AND account_id IN (216223)
ORDER BY account_id, order_id DESC, order_validfrom_date, order_validto_date
```

Both options will result with below output

```
Row account_id  order_id    start_date  end_date    ranking  
1   216223      482847      2017-10-09  2017-11-08  1    
2   216223      472121      2017-10-09  2017-11-08  2    
3   216223      312312      2017-10-09  2017-11-08  3
```